# How to grep "&amount"?

Tags: grep

I need to look for `&amount` in a file but it throws error -

```
[1] 25950
amount: Command not found.
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
```

What is the right way to search for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in quotes like

```
grep '&amount' file
```

so the `&` isn't interpreted by the shell to put the `grep` in the background and then try to run the command `amount`

or alternately, you could escape it so it won't have the special meaning to the shell:

```
grep \&amount file
```